# Add data from ado DB to treeview

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Ok I have a Ado DB  table name is [pass] fields are

```
[id]
[Machine]
[Level]
[Username]
[Password]
```

I would like to show all the records in tree view like this

```
[Machine]
--|Level|
----Username
----Password
--|Level|
----username
----Password
[Machine]
--|Level|
----username
----Password
```

ect..

I know how to connect to db but not sure how to inport the data to the tree and declear it as a node or sublevel item.

Thanks
Glen

current code.

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Qry:TADOQuery;
  selected : string;
  i:integer;
begin
    Qry:=TADOquery.Create(Self);
    try
       qry.Connection := dbconnection;
       qry.SQL.Clear;
       qry.SQL.Add('Select * FROM [Pass]');
       qry.Open;
       Qry.First;
       i:=1;
       with qry do
       begin
           while qry.RecordCount >= i do
           begin

           end;
       end;
    finally
        Qry.Active:=False;
        Qry.Free;
    end;

end;
```

Comment: Did you Google ("delphi ttreeview tutorial")? You could have found e.g. the excellent TTreeview tutorial by Andre v.d. Merwe at http://users.iafrica.com/d/da/dart/zen/Articles/TTreeView/TTreeView_Main.html

Comment: i did delphi treeview keep getting results by About.com which where not really helping me much , ill try that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good starting point I believe. I use it in my application to load two tables:

```
procedure TdlgTestsSections.LoadSections;
var
  AllSectionsNode, SectionNode, SubSectionNode, AllParamsNode,
  i: Integer;
begin
  tvSections.Items.Clear;
  AllSectionsNode := tvSections.Items.AddNode(nil, nil, 'All Sections',
    Pointer(0), naAddFirst);
  dmLabData.qTestSections.Requery;
  while not dmLabData.qTestSections.Eof do
  begin
    SectionNode := tvSections.Items.AddNode(nil, AllSectionsNode,
      dmLabData.qTestSectionsName.Value,
      Pointer(dmLabData.qTestSectionsID.Value), naAddChild);
    dmLabData.qTestSubSections.First;
    while not dmLabData.qTestSubSections.Eof do
    begin
      SubSectionNode := tvSections.Items.AddNode(nil, SectionNode,
        dmLabData.qTestSubSectionsName.Value,
        Pointer(dmLabData.qTestSubSectionsRowNo.Value), naAddChild);
      SubSectionNode.Expanded := False;
      dmLabData.qTestSubSections.Next;
    end;
    dmLabData.qTestSections.Next;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I can follow what your doing, but the whole idea of it is confusing to me. well i guess its more of the treeview data that is confusing me. let me research the treeview component a little more.

Comment: Just remember that each treeview node can have a parent. In your case, the node you create for `Level` is the parent of both `UserName` and `Password`, and has `Machine` as its own parent